# How to get the data given in a table from jsp page consisting of jasper report to PDF

Tags: javascript, jsp, jasper-reports

[image]

[image]

When i click on "Add Row" button, a new row is created, likewise when i click on "Add Row" button 3 times,3 new rows are created as shown below

[image]

Then we will add data into the table and click on "submit" button it is showing the data in a browser so everything is fine,my question is how the data given in the table(it may be 3 rows of data or 4 rows of data or even 100 rows of data) can be send from jsp page(contains jasper report) to PDF

In eclipse the jsp code is as given below. what changes or what code should i write so that the table will be successfully exported to PDF

quotation.jsp

```
    <script language="javascript">
                // Add row to the HTML table

                function addRow() {    
                    var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); //html table
                    var rowCount = table.rows.length; //no. of rows in table
                    var columnCount =  table.rows[0].cells.length; //no. of columns in table          
                    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); //insert a row            

                    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); //create a new cell           
                    var element1 = document.createElement("input"); //create a new element           
                    element1.type = "checkbox"; //set the element type 
                    element1.setAttribute('id', 'newCheckbox'); //set the id attribute         
                    cell1.appendChild(element1); //append element to cell

                    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);            
                    var element2 = document.createElement("input");            
                    element2.type = "text"; 
                    element2.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                    element2.setAttribute('name', 'sl'+rowCount);
                    element2.setAttribute('style', 'width: 50px');
                    cell2.appendChild(element2);      

                    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);            
                    var element3 = document.createElement("input");            
                    element3.type = "text"; 
                    element3.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                    element3.setAttribute('name', 'item'+rowCount);
                    cell3.appendChild(element3);         

                    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);            
                    var element4 = document.createElement("input");            
                    element4.type = "textarea"; 
                    element4.setAttribute('rows', '4');
                    element4.setAttribute('cols','20');
                    element4.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                    element4.setAttribute('name', 'discription'+rowCount);
                    cell4.appendChild(element4);


                    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);            
                    var element5 = document.createElement("input");            
                    element5.type = "text"; 
                    element5.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                    element5.setAttribute('name', 'quantity'+rowCount);
                    element5.setAttribute('style', 'width: 50px');
                    cell5.appendChild(element5);

                    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);            
                    var element6 = document.createElement("input");            
                    element6.type = "text"; 
                    element6.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                    element6.setAttribute('name', 'price'+rowCount);
                    cell6.appendChild(element6);

                    var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);            
                    var element7 = document.createElement("input");            
                    element7.type = "text"; 
                    element7.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                    element7.setAttribute('name', 'CST'+rowCount);
                    element7.setAttribute('style', 'width: 50px');
                    cell7.appendChild(element7);




                    var cell8 = row.insertCell(7); //create a new cell           
                    var element8 = document.createElement("input"); //create a new element           
                    element8.type = "checkbox"; //set the element type 
                    element8.setAttribute('id', 'vat5'); //set the id attribute 
                    element8.setAttribute('name','tax'+rowCount);
                    element8.setAttribute('value','vat5');
                    cell8.appendChild(element8);

                    var cell9 = row.insertCell(8); //create a new cell      
                    var element9 = document.createElement("input"); //create a new element           
                    element9.type = "checkbox"; //set the element type 
                    element9.setAttribute('id', 'vat14'); //set the id attribute 
                    element9.setAttribute('name','tax'+rowCount);
                    element9.setAttribute('value','vat14')  ;     
                    cell9.appendChild(element9);

                    var cell10 = row.insertCell(9); //create a new cell      
                    var element10 = document.createElement("input"); //create a new element           
                    element10.type = "checkbox"; //set the element type 
                    element10.setAttribute('id', 'serviceTax'); //set the id attribute 
                    element10.setAttribute('name','tax'+rowCount);    
                    element10.setAttribute('value','serviceTax');
                    cell10.appendChild(element10);


                } 
    </script>
    <body>
<form name="form" action="quotationdisplay.jsp" method="post">
    <table id="my_table" align="center" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <thead><tr>

                                            <th>Select</th>
                                            <th>Sl_no</th>
                                            <th>Item</th>
                                            <th>Description</th>
                                            <th>Quantity</th>
                                            <th>Price/Unit</th>
                                            <th>CST%</th>
                                            <th>VAT5.5</th>
                                            <th>VAT14.5</th>
                                            <th>ServiceTax</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
 <input type="button" value="Add row" name="add" onClick="addRow()" />
</form>
    </body>
```

quotationdisplay.jsp

```
<%  
            int sum = 0;
             Connection con = null;
            String row = request.getParameter("rowCount");          

            int rowCount = Integer.parseInt(row);
          System.out.println("rowCount=" + rowCount);
           int i = 1;
           while (i < rowCount) {
               System.out.println("in while i="+i);
               String sli = request.getParameter("sl" + i).trim();
               System.out.println("in while i"+sli);
               String itemi = request.getParameter("item" + i).trim();
               System.out.println("in while i"+itemi);
               String discriptioni = request.getParameter("discription" + i).trim();
               System.out.println("in while i"+discriptioni);
                String quantityi = request.getParameter("quantity" + i).trim();
                System.out.println("in while iquantityi="+quantityi);
                String pricei = request.getParameter("price" + i).trim();             
                System.out.println("in while i pricei ="+pricei);
               int p = Integer.parseInt(pricei);
                int q = Integer.parseInt(quantityi);
                int t = p * q;
               sum = sum + t;
               i = i + 1;
           }
       %>
 <tr id="table">
                <td>

                    <table id="my_table" align="center" style="border: 1px solid " cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="border: 1px solid">Sl.no</th>
                                <th style="border: 1px solid">Item</th>
                                <th style="border: 1px solid">Description</th>
                                <th style="border: 1px solid">Quantity</th>
                                <th style="border: 1px solid">Price/Unit</th>
                                <th style="border: 1px solid">Total Amount</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <%
                                int j = 1;
                                while (j < rowCount) {%>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="border: 1px solid"><%= request.getParameter("sl" + j)%>

                                </td>
                                <td style="border: 1px solid"><%= request.getParameter("item" + j)%></td>
                                <td style="border: 1px solid"><%= request.getParameter("discription" + j)%></td>
                                <%int q = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("quantity" + j));%>
                                <td style="border: 1px solid"><%= q%></td>
                                <% int p = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("price" + j));%>
                                <td style="border: 1px solid"><%= p%></td>
                                <td style="border: 1px solid"><%= (q * p)%></td>
                                <%j++;%>
                            </tr>
                            <%}%>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="total">
                <td style="text-align: right;border: 1px solid #000">
                    Total: <%= sum%>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="border: 1px solid">
                    <%
                        int to = (int) sum;
                        NumToWords w = new NumToWords();
                        String words = w.convert(to);
                        String upper = words.toUpperCase();
                    %>
                    INR : <b><%= upper%> ONLY </b>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes if they are not on database you need to setup your own [JRDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDataSource.html)

Normally in java we use the [JRBeanCollectionDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html) (passing object in a list) but in your case I think the easiest way is to use the [JRMapCollectionDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRMapCollectionDataSource.html)

example

```
List<Map<String,Object>> ds = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> ();
for (all my rows in the table) {
  Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  map.put("col1", getValueFromCol1());
  map.put("col2", getValueFromCol2());
  ecc....
  ds.add(map);
}           
JRMapCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRMapCollectionDataSource(ds);

// TO get the print past the dataSource instead of connection
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, yourParametersMap, dataSource);
```

In your .jrxml the field names will be

```
<field name="col1" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="col2" class="java.lang.String"/>
...ecc..
```

assuming that you past String into the map otherwise you need to adjust to relative class.

and naturally your number of records will be the same as the size of the `ds`.

Comment: what if they are from the database??.I mean the columns shown above are there in the database

Comment: If they are in database pass connection and query to view them, don't really understand then what is the problem?, the query?

Comment: yeah the problem is query, i mean looping is there. So how to pass the data??